# Overriding UseBufferedInputStream in Web Api when Attribute Routing is in use

Tags: asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I want to override the buffered input stream for a particular end point which is responsible for upload the files.

I've been following the advice in the great article here:

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/

And this approach works whenever a templating approach to routing is taken. Like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

However, whenever I use attribute based routing,

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Then the RouteData is never populated:

```
public override bool UseBufferedInputStream(object hostContext)
{
        var context = hostContext as HttpContextBase;

        if (context != null && context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.Count>0)
        {
            if (string.Equals(context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), "values", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Is there another approach I can use, a different way of checking the route data for the request, in order to determine if I want the input buffered?

Comment: You want to override it why?

Comment: So I can upload very large files. I need to turn buffering off or web api will hold the entire file in memory until it's been complet